# Polyglossia not understanding \textlang{}

Tags: polyglossia

I am trying to use `\textlang{}` as described on page 15, line 10 of the Polyglossia manual, but failing to understand the error message complaining that the language is not loaded:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=austrian]{german}
\setlanguagealias*[variant=austrian]{german}{AT}

\begin{document}

\textlang{AT}{Das ist auf Österreichisch.}

\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
! Critical Package polyglossia Error: The language at is not loaded. You
(polyglossia)                         should load it.
```

Anyone could shed some light on what is going on?

Comment: No idea, but it works if you replace `AT` by `at` in both places

Comment: I used capitals because that is straight out of the example on the previous page, and that works fine with `\setlanguagealias` as opposed to `\setlanguagealias*`.

Comment: yes I realise that:  I just guessed lowercase as it mentioned `at` not `AT` in the message, and the guess seemed to work, Working might be better than following the documentation:-)

Comment: see https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/commit/d3027374d0ac2f3ddc00b067292d23983a32a9dd

Comment: @UdiFogiel, I am not sure I understand this -- I am using ver. 1.64 and the comment say "language options are lowercased before they are handled". Are "language tags" ALSO lowercased? This is definitely not a case of option. How does it work for `\setlanguagealias` an not to `\setlanguagealias*` I would expect it to work for both or none. How does the manual continues to have examples with `\textAT` ?

Comment: the problem is with `\textlang`, for some reason the language tag is being lowredcase and not the options: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/blob/87a478951cdeb70739785a63a8e2b9b36a9d3094/tex/polyglossia.sty#L1982  probably just a mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been ideintified by Udi Fogiel, in the comments above and fixed by Jürgen Spitzmüller for release 1.66 of Polyglossia.